# Jquery AJAX calling is not returing success

Tags: python, jquery

I am a novice and written a code using Jquery to display an output of a python program on a browser to a user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Project</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#runReport').click(function() {
        runreport($('#starttime').val(), $('#endtime').val());
    });

    function runreport(startdate, enddate) {
        $('.date').html('<img src=img/load.gif alt=loading.../>');
        alert ('this is a test ' + startdate + ' enddate ' + enddate);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/~prakash_prasad/project/runreport.py",
            data: {
                  'startTime': startdate,
                  'endTime':   enddate
              },
              success: function(result) {
                  alert ('Success' );
                  $("p").html(result);
              },
              error:function(xhr,err) {
                  alert("Failed\nreadyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status + "\nresponseText: "+xhr.responseText);
              }
          });
      }
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').datepicker({
        flat: true,
        date: '2012-03-10',
        current: '2012-03-10',
        calendars: 1,
        starts: 1
     });
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Start Date : <input type="text" name="startdate" id="starttime" class="date"/>
End   Date : <input type="text" name="enddate" id="endtime" class="date"/>
<button id="runReport">Run Report</button>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load this html code in browser I get the below alert messages in sequence:

First alert message:

```
this is a test 03/10/2012 enddate 03/30/2012
```

Second alert message:

```
Failed
readyState: 0
status: 0
responseText:
```

The runreport.py code is::

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import cgi
import MySQLdb
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import json


print 'Content-Type: text/html\n'
print '<html><body>'
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
starttime = form["startTime"].value
endtime = form["endTime"].value
print '<b>%s</b>' % (starttime)
print '<b>%s</b>' % (endtime)
print '</body></html>'
```

I had ran my python code and it works fine.

```
project>$ curl "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/~prakash_prasad/project/runreport.py?startTime=2011-03-09&endTime=2012-03-07"
<html><body>
<b>2011-03-09</b>
<b>2012-03-07</b>
</body></html>
```

Why am I not able to achieve the objective to render html output of my python script to browser?

==================================================================================

I downloaded Firebug and below is the logs I see in Net Tab:

```
Headers
Response Headersview source
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/plain
Date    Sun, 11 Mar 2012 17:08:45 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Server  Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) PHP/5.3.3 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 mod_jk/1.2.31 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.8.8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked



Request Headersview source
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Host    xx.xx.xx.xx
Origin  http://tools
Referer http://tools/~prakash_prasad/project/p.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2


http://xx.xx.xx.xx/~prakash_prasad/project/runreport.py?startTime=03%2F09%2F2012&endTime=03%2F23%2F2012     Size 64B Status 200 OK Domain same host where my HTML file is there
```

Please advise.

==================================================================================

!!!!!SOLVED!!!!!

The issue was I was using the AJAX URL construct wrongly:

```
url:  "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/~prakash_prasad/project/runreport.py",
```

When I changed it to :

```
url:  "runreport.py",
```

It worked perfectly

Please advise what is the difference via above two Ajax URL call via Jquery - though doamin is same for the python script and html file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

First, add `print "200 OK"` *before* you print out the Content-Type.  Second, make sure that you are sending over *two* blank lines if you are going to be building entire responses yourself:

```
print '200 OK' # Status codes are helpful
# Two blank lines between headers and body are required
print 'Content-Type: text/html\n\n'
print '<html><body>'
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
starttime = form["startTime"].value
endtime = form["endTime"].value
print '<b>%s</b>' % (starttime)
print '<b>%s</b>' % (endtime)
print '</body></html>'
```